# API Timezone Parameter ignored by CURL

Tags: api, curl, character-encoding

I have a Problem with the URL-Encoded Timezone parameter (Europe%2FBerlin) in an API request:

My API Request to get a data feed from thingspeak:

```
https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/CHANNELID/feed.csv?api_key=APIKEY&timezone=Europe%2FBerlin
```

If I post this into the Browser the Timezone Parameter is recognised and displayed correctly.

If I put the request into a curl command like this:

```
curl -o /Path/To/File.csv https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/CHANNELID/feed.csv?api_key=APIKEY&timezone=Europe%2FBerlin
```

... the timezone parameter is ignored.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By quoting the URL. Put it within double quotes.

The '&'-symbol is treated special by the shell and is used to put the command in the background and then treat what's on the right side of it as a second, separate command.

Comment: thank you I had a bit of a Problem since I am using the API Request within a Python script via subprocess call. but I got it to work now. the problem was the missing "